# spring boot feign client getting HTTP 404

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am currently just checking how to use Feign as Declarative REST client in one of my project.

following is Feign Client

```
@FeignClient(name = "SEARCHCABMS",configuration = AppFeignConfiguration.class)
       public interface SearchCabMsClient {

        @RequestMapping(value = "api/searchcab/locationcabtimedetail/search/getCabForLocationAfterTimeSlot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        String  searchCabDetails(@PathVariable("fromDate") String fromDate, 
                                @PathVariable("locationId") long locationId,
                                @PathVariable("isdeleted") byte isdeleted,
                                @PathVariable("hourforbooking")int hourforbooking);
    }
```

This interface is autowired in one service

```
@Autowired
SearchCabMsClient restService;
```

Added EnableFeignClients to SpringBootApplication

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.gp.cabbooking.services.feign"})
```

Dependencies,parent etc  in pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I can able to see while debugging spring create proxy for my feign client 
i tried calling this service with the help of ribbon and it is working fine 
but when i execute  method define in my feign client . i am getting **feign.FeignException: status 404 reading**

```
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading SearchCabMsClient#searchCabDetails(String,long,byte,int)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar:8.16.2]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar:8.16.2]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:134) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar:8.16.2]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-8.16.2.jar:8.16.2]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:97) ~[feign-hystrix-8.16.2.jar:8.16.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:293) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50) ~[rxjava-1.1.5.jar:1.1.5]
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a `feign.ErrorDecoder`. Please read this for more information
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/118

You can also add `decode404=true` in your FeignClient annotation definition.

Comment: This answer deserved to be accepted. 
In case of `Feign.builder()`, just add `.decode404`.

Comment: Adding `decode404 = true` in `@FeignClient` resolved the issue for me. What is the meaning of decode404 boolean?

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined the url of the service you reach to using this feign client? 404 is a not found issue.

```
  @FeignClient(name = "SEARCHCABMS", url = "${SEARCHCABMS.service.url}", 
  configuration = ClientConfiguration.class)
  public interface SearchCabMsClient {

  }
```

Having a reference holder in url helps to externalize it and configure for each environment.

If you did configured the URL, double the check the rest endpoint.

Comment: spring cloud feign should be invoked based on the app name with out using url right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that? As far as this answer goes, feign client either from openfeign or spring cloud, doesn't matter. Its just a http client implementation. So you do need to provide the URL it needs to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It is a routing issue. Just add / at the start in @RequestMapping path in FeignClient. Also, path variables are not defined in the path. I recommend define they as @RequestParam. Then the path is correct except  / at the start.

```
@FeignClient(name = "SEARCHCABMS",configuration = AppFeignConfiguration.class)
   public interface SearchCabMsClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/searchcab/locationcabtimedetail/search/getCabForLocationAfterTimeSlot/{fromDate}/{locationId}/{isdeleted}/{hourforbooking}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String  searchCabDetails(@PathVariable("fromDate") String fromDate, 
                            @PathVariable("locationId") long locationId,
                            @PathVariable("isdeleted") byte isdeleted,
                            @PathVariable("hourforbooking")int hourforbooking);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers suggest putting the `url` attribute to `@FeignClient`, but when the architecture involves registering the service (*Eureka Client*) with the *Eureka Server*, I think, there is no liberty to use the `url` attribute.
 
It is the *service-id* or the *eureka-id* that has to be used for the purpose of rest calls.
So, with the `client-side discovery architecture`,

```
@FeignClient(name = "service-id", url = "${service.url}", configuration=SomeConfig.class)
```

may no longer be the *scalable* solution to the 
`status 404 reading IFeignClient#someControllerMethod()` error.

I faced the same error in my `client-side discovery architecture` app. The issue was this  entry in the `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /myapp
```

Removing it helped resolve the issue by correct `url`. The exact declaration that my working app has: `@FeignClient(name="${service-id}")`

Hope this helps someone with similar issue.

Comment: Instead of removing context-path from application.yml you could have added /myapp as a prefix path to declarative methed of Feign client  for example  @RequestMapping(value = "/myapp/remaining path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        String  feignMethod(...);

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the server.servlet.context-path: ##some name##, remove it and set the application name displayed in EUREKA server home page.