# Feign + Eureka without springboot

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, feign, openfeign

I need to use **Feign** and **Eureka** from spring app to call a microservice which is registered on Eureka server.

From the **OpenFeign** github page [here](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) I found how to use feign in spring.

I couldn't find anywhere how to use Eureka and Feign together in spring

How can I use Eureka service discovery with Feign **without springboot**?

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910746/spring-boot-feign-client-getting-http-404/59510494#59510494

Comment: @Adarsh That one was using sprinboot. Also I have already found usage guide for using feign in spring but my problem is using it along with eureka in spring